# Why my YoloV3 model cant detect properly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

i have problem with my yolov3 model. My model can't detect objects with new data and no bounding box appears, but detects properly with training data.
I have finished training my dataset with 18000 images. Has 6 classes with 3000 images in each class and with yolov3.cfg as below:

```
batch=32
subdivisions=8
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 12000
policy=steps
steps=9600,10800
scales=.1,.1
```

I think there is nothing wrong with this config.
The training finished with 0.09 avg loss and and got 99% mAP.

[image: yolov3_custom_final.weights map]

[image: Test with data training]

This is the result when testing with training data.

[image: Test with new data for testing]

This is the result when testing with new data. It can be seen that the model does not detect anything, no bounding box appears. I have also tried using other new data but it still produces the same result, no bounding box appears.

Below is the chart generated when the training is complete:
[image: yolov3 chart]

What does the chart above mean? what's wrong with my model? and is there anything I missed during training?

Any help, I'm very grateful.

Comment: that is a really high mAP score. It's probably overfit on the training data. Did you gather your images from video?

Comment: @IanChu Yes sir, I extracted the video into several frames/images for training. In 1 video can be split into 300 frames/images. Is there another way to do training with video data?

Comment: Video data is especially easy to overfit. Images from one frame to the next look extremely similar. The best training data is when each example is different. Try only taking one frame out of every two seconds of video. Also, don't use images from a video in both the training and validation set. This will give you an inflated validation score since the network will have seen nearly the same images in the training set.

Comment: Don't worry about having a much smaller training set. Try it out first and gather more data later if needed. You should have a mAP score between 0.4 and 0.7 if things are working.

Comment: I really grateful for your advice, i will try asap, thank you so much @IanChu.